# How to install new Intel Ethernet driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel, ethernet

Ubuntu 12.04 x64 doesn't recognize newest Intel Ethernet adapter on my desktop (Intel Ethernet Connection i217-V). I downloaded required driver from Intel and compiled it using make. Now I have:

```
alex@alex64-six:~$ find / -name 'e1000e.ko' 2>/dev/null
/home/alex/Documents/IntelEthernetDriver/e1000e-3.0.4/src/e1000e.ko
/lib/modules/3.2.0-64-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko
```

The first line is new driver compiled from Intel sources. The second line is probably existing driver from Ubuntu distribution, which doesn't recognize new Ethernet adapter. How can I apply the new driver instead of existing one?

Any other solution is welcome. For now, I cannot upgrade to latest Ubuntu release, because I use some third-party products.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing Common ethernet drivers containing package :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`
```